# GSM AT COMMAND | How to upload .amr audio file

Tags: gsm, at-command

I can list the directory using below command.
AT+FSLS=\

i found AT+FSCREATE="1.amr",3 command to crate files in directory but the problem is, how to upload the file from my local drive.

Comment: Check AT-command manual of your modem. There is probably separate AT-command for writing to a file. For example: AT+FSWRITE

Comment: @Ski thx u for your response, yes manual has below command at+fswrite=1.arm,1,512,10. nothing else,how to load from local drive is my main problem

Comment: Then you should tell little bit more about your environment. Like programming language. And also possible code-snipped what you have already tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have any modem that supports `AT+FSWRITE` command. 
But based on SIMcom AT-command manual, `AT+FSWRITE=` command responds with prompt: `>`.
Manual does not clearly tell how to use the command.

But it might work similar way than `AT+CMGS=` command:

1. Send `AT+FSWRITE=1.arm,0,512,10` command to modem.
2. Wait `>` from the modem.
3. Write content of the file (512 bytes) to the modem.
4. Send Ctrl-Z char (0x1A hex) to the modem.
5. Wait OK/ERROR from the modem.

Step 4. may not be needed, because size of the file is in the command.

Comment: so i need to write audio file in hex format right ?

Comment: i can successfully write the file now. but its not playing. i can only hear noise. any idea where i went wrong ?

Comment: @Anto sujesh  If you wrote it by using hex format. Did you already tried to use pure binary?

Comment: what i did is, i opened arm in notepad, copy it and write it on gsm.

Comment: how exactly do you do step 3 ?

Comment: @Xsmael : Step 3 depends on your programming language and maybe also OS. And usually there are several ways to do it. For example: with Linux writing to a modem is often done by using  [write() function](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write).

Comment: @SKi Thanks for replying I am using nodeJS with serialport module, but if you can give me a working exemple with any other language I'll me more than glad! coz I have tried many things but to no avail.